# TeX4ht shows error "v'^\dagger_i " while using align environment but not in inline equation

Tags: tex4ht, xhtml

TeX4ht shows error "v'^\dagger_i " while using align environment but not in inline equation.

The pdflatex not shown error both inline and align environment

The Tex4ht error as follow:
! Double superscript.
 \s:p

l.6 \end{align}

Answer (score 2):

TeX4ht [needs proper grouping for subscripts and superscripts](https://tug.org/tex4ht/doc/mml.html), especially in the MathML mode. So when you use multiple tokens, like `v'` as a part of your expression, you need to add braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
${v'}^{\dagger}_{i} $

\begin{align}
{v'}^\dagger_i  = v
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]